# Setting Binding on Switch in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding, uiswitch

I am using `Switch` to toggle some value.

```
<Switch x:Name="masterSwitch"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" IsToggled="{Binding Value}"/>
```

Value is the parameter of record in table:

```
public class MasterSwitch
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

But how do I specify which table look to?
I want the switch be bound to `MasterSwitch` table(the one I've got model for).

DO I set the `BindingContext` in xaml?

Comment: the switch will inherit the page's BindingContext, or you can set a different one via XAML/code for just that element

Comment: Also I recommend you to separate your models which you are using for Binding.